# Angular retrieve specific data into $scope variable is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I initialize here

```
 $scope.statuses = [];
```

Then if I simply set the data from $http.get to the $scope variable, that "works" but I need to filter it down more.

```
$scope.statuses = result.data.Devices; 
console.log($scope.statuses);
```

That returns the array of data like this in dev tools console output

> 0: Object
>     $$hashKey
>   :
>   "object:5"
>   Aid
>   :
>   "oAAABTUAAg=="
>   DKiIndex
>   :
>   "DKi00000002"
>   DefaultPayload
>   :
>   "C:\ProgramData\"
>   DeviceId
>   :
>   "00022B9A000000010001"
>   DeviceStatus
>   :
>   3
>   ManifestIdList
>   :
>   Array[3]
>   PendingManifestId
>   :
>   null
>   PendingTimeStamp
>   :
>   "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
>   Sha
>   :
>   "R2tiZRQgY/iohXZt5O4HaQwtVe/adWU2VOcKaelJ3Us="
>   StagedManifestIdList
>   :
>   Array[0]

However I only WANT some specific data

```
$scope.statuses = result.data.Devices.DeviceStatus;
```

Why does it say 'undefined' and how do I do this?

So   0: Object     DeviceStatus  is there..   :/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DeviceController as vm">


...
        <tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices">
             <td>{{device.DeviceId}}</td>
             <td>{{device.DeviceStatus}}</td>
             <td>{{device.Aid}}</td>
             <td>{{device.Sha}}</td>
        </tr>
...
```

Essentially I wish to manipulate the data in Javascript /angular  (.js)  before it makes it to the ng-repeat loop

Thus is $scope even the proper thing to even be using?

I know that I have some data to change for example

Some data in a field was surrounded by  []  e.g.  [01,02,03]  so doing 
{{ device.aid.join(',') }}  would "fix" the [] issue but i need to have some function like this?   where can i use this?

```
// usage {{displayArchived(item.archives)}}
$scope.displayArchived = function(archives){
    return (archives.length > 0) ? archives.join(',') : 'none';
};
```

Then will a "let" help for numbers of DeviceStatus?

```
  let statuses = ['Old Device', 'New Device', 'Activated', 'Unactivated'];
```

Comment: You have an `array`, you must specify the position(index) that you want to get the `DeviceStatus`. Ex. If you want to get the first DeviceStatus: `$scope.statuses = result.data.Devices[0].DeviceStatus;`.

Comment: {{ device.DeviceStatus }}  was in my html ,  so i am wanting to capture each value in the ng-repeat     ,  i do want to manipulate it a bit with a function

Comment: Show your HTML then

Comment: Yes, very sorry -   editing question now.  greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, `result.data.Devices` is an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[
   {DeviceId : "00022B9A000000010001" DeviceStatus : 3 .... },
   {DeviceId : "00022B9A000030011111" DeviceStatus : 9 ...},
   ....
]
```

So when you try to get `result.data.Devices.DeviceStatus`, there is no array element called `DeviceStatus`, which is why you are getting back `undefined`.

You will need to iterate through the array of Devices to get a specific Device's `DeviceStatus`:

```
angular.forEach(result.data.Devices, function(value, index){
           $scope.statuses.push(value.DeviceStatus);
         });
```

or you can access directly if you know which device you want:

```
var index = 1;
$scope.statuses = result.data.Devices[index].DeviceStatus;
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get all of the devices and display {{ device.DeviceStatus }} with your template, here is a solution:

Code:

```
$scope.devices = result.data.Devices;
```

Template:

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices">
    {{ device.DeviceStatus }} 
</div>
```

In our code, we assign the `request.data.Devices` array to `$scope.devices`. Then in the template, we use `ng-repeat` to go through each `device` in `$scope.devices` and display the device's `DeviceStatus`.

**EDIT2:**

In order to match the DeviceStatus to it's actual name, you can create a custom filter.

In your code create the filter:

```
app.filter('deviceStatus', function () {
  return function (status_id) {
      var statuses = ['Old Device', 'New Device', 'Activated', 'Unactivated'];
      return statuses[status_id];
  };
});
```

You can use the new filter in your template now:

```
<td>{{device.DeviceId | deviceStatus}}</td>
```

We pipe the `DeviceId` into our custom `deviceStatus` filter in order to get the correct status name in the template.

Comment: I added more code ,  I need to see if a DeviceStatus = 1 then DeviceStatus  = "Activated"  else if  DeviceStatus = 2  then DeviceStatus = "Unactived "  etc..    How can I achieve that?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @JeremyMiller  I added info on how to check the device status code with a custom filter.

Comment: `app` is not defined      also   push of undefined

Comment: I posted a new question and this time I have a Plunker which should help you see how I have the application setup .  I'm watching videos and learning....  I appreciate your help    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242795/angular-filtering-data-in-javascript-is-not-displaying-results-and-push-of-data