# Angular filtering data in javascript is not displaying results and push of data causes error plunker provided

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok, seems that I was having too many issues with the way in which my Angular site is setup, so I put it in a plunker as then anyone can see it.

Original question:   [Angular retrieve specific data into $scope variable is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239540/angular-retrieve-specific-data-into-scope-variable-is-not-working)

**Plunker**
http://plnkr.co/edit/NsE29zjraQp9UeklJBiI?p=preview

My issues are
1. i'm not understanding how to use  app.filter 
2. Issue with app name
3. forEach with push inside $http.get throws error not defined

The plunker Index.html has the template code loop ,  app.module.js is root and the device.controller.js is where I'm using controller with $http.get call using json file to fake it.

I was attempting to use the other persons answer so this code

```
$scope.devices = result.data.Devices;   // gives all data ...
```

Filter I was wondering if this with work

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices">
    {{ device.DeviceStatus }} 
</div>
```

Then this code I'm not sure it in the correct "place"

seems like i'm not understanding "app"

```
app.filter('deviceStatus', function () {
    return function (status_id) {
       var statuses = ['Old Device', 'New Device', 'Activated', 'Unactivated'];
       return statuses[status_id];
   };
});
```

Example filter:

```
<td>{{device.DeviceId | deviceStatus}}</td>
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve. Plz provide some explanation.

Comment: 2 links provided    original question in which i am told to try  app.filter  so in plunker u see that i chain that in top of controller js file ,  and i'm trying to get foreach loop with push to work and that throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to understand your issue.

As per your question, it seems that you have problems understanding what `app` is and how to use `filter`.

This is the working version of your plunkr. [Check this url](http://plnkr.co/edit/PrP76Ut7nkohDX8ZVSGq?p=preview)

1. `app` in your project is the `ng-app` directive. The `ng-app` directive tells AngularJS that the element is the "owner" of an AngularJS application.
2. For understanding filter functionality. check the below example.
3. You were trying to push into `$scope.statuses` which is not defined yet. So first define `$scope.statuses` to be an empty array i.e `$scope.statuses = [];

Hope this works for you!`

```js
// To declare a filter we pass in two parameters to app.filter

// The first parameter is the name of the filter 
// second is a function that will return another function that does the actual work of the filter

//here app is the module name of your project

app.filter('myFilter', function() {

  // In the return function, we must pass in a single parameter which will be the data we will work on.
  // We have the ability to support multiple other parameters that can be passed into the filter optionally
  return function(input, optional1, optional2) {

    var output;

    // Do filter work here

    return output;

  }

});
```

Comment: Awesome!     quick question    -  why do some people do this  `var app = angular.module('demoApp',['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);`    as opposed to how i'm doing this  `angular.module('app', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);`  ?

Comment: When you define a module in your project, the best practice is to put it inside a global variable or any such, so that you can directly assign the module to any component next time. 

For e.g: `angular.module('app', [dependencies])` looks good if your application is too small. But when you go for large and scalable applications it is preferred to have a usage like 

`var app = angular.module('app', []);`

so that we can start writing the other part of code like 

`app.filter('filtername', function(){}).controller('controllerName', function(){})` etc.,